# 'Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null' when trying to load external TypeScript component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

I have something in place where I can build my components using this npx command (run in PowerShell):

```
&npx vue-cli-service build `
    --target lib `
    --formats umd-min `
    --no-clean `
    --dest $destinationFolder `
    --name $component.Name $component.FullName
```

and then I import those into my vue app as per [this article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/)

It works fine when the components are written using JS, but as soon as I try to make one in TS I get this error:

```
file:7 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Module.fb15 (file:7)
    at r (file:1)
    at 8875 (file:1)
    at file:1
    at file:1
    at file:1
```

My TypeScript vue component is really simple:

```
<template>
<h1>A lovely typescript component</h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    name: 'TypeScriptTest'
})
export default class TypeScriptTest extends Vue { }
</script>
```

I did try importing vue like this instead:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

but it had no effect

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to the top of my html file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

And the errors went way, and my TypeScript comopnents imported successfully

This does not seem like an ideal solution, but it does work